# Quotient of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can $(x-1)/((x-1)(x+2))$ and $(x-2)/((x-1)(x+2))$ be simplified (with the notation referring to principal ideals in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x])?$

I am not sure what their elements are.

In general, how do we deal with $(f)/(f,g),$ a quotient of two ideals?

Comment: $(f,g)$ is not two ideals, it's one ideal generated by two elements.  Also $\mathbb R[x]$ is a PID so $(f,g)=(h)$ for some $h$.  This doesn't answer your question but I hope clears it up slightly.

Comment: Where did the OP say it is two ideals?

Comment: Look up the [Third Isomorphism Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Rings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element in $\;\langle x-1\rangle\;$ is of the form $\;(x-1)g(x)\;,\;\;g(x)\in\Bbb R\;$ , so in the quotient

$$(x-1)g(x)+\langle x-1\rangle\langle x-2\rangle=(x-1)f(x)+\langle x-1\rangle\langle x-2\rangle\iff$$

$$(x-1)(g(x)-f(x))\in\langle x-1\rangle\langle x-2\rangle\iff g(x)-f(x)\in\langle x-2\rangle\iff$$

$$g(x)-f(x)=(x-2)h(x)\;,\;\;h(x)\in\Bbb R$$